# How to store meta data about a collection in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I see it quite often I come across this problem about storing some meta additional information about a collection.

Is there any way on Firestore to save some meta information in a collection? Like what this collection is maintained for or some other custom properties.

For example : When saving leaderboard scores, if we need to know if the scores need to be sorted ascending or descending when queried, its good if we store this info in the collection.

Else, we need to go for extra reads when ever we need the to sort the scores. Can any one suggest?

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/):

> Following Cloud Firestore's NoSQL data model, **you store data in
>   documents** that contain fields mapping to values. These documents are
>   stored in collections, **which are containers for your documents** that
>   you can use to organize your data and build queries.

In other words, the "data container" in Firestore is the Document. Collections are only Document containers and cannot hold data (i.e. "fields mapping to values").

So if you want to store extra information on a specific Collection (i.e. metadata) you will have to do that in a Document. And yes, it will require an extra read to query the Document containing these metadata.